# How can I get VSCode to connect to Xdebug with Docker

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

PHP version:  7.2
Xdebug version: 2.6.0
Adapter version:  1.12.1
Example Repo: https://github.com/makeshift3ds/vscode-xdebug-docker

I am having trouble getting VSCode to connect to Xdebug running in Docker. I've followed examples and tutorials but feel like something is missing.

Notes:
- if I start the debugger in VSCode, the debugger output says `success: true` in the object. But the xdebug logs in the docker container show no activity. However, if I run the PHP script from the php-fpm container Xdebug logs look healthy.

```
Log opened at 2018-03-13 15:29:11
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.18.0.1:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.2.3" protocol_version="1.0" appid="7" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="2.6.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2018-03-13 15:29:11
```

- if I attempt a connection in VSCode and try to evaluate some code it says there is no connection.
- php-fpm is running on port 9000 so I setup Xdebug on 9001. I can see the ports are open.

-

```
vpnkit          59029 makeshift   19u     IPv4 0x7784b9d434951b53        0t0     TCP *:9001 (LISTEN)
vpnkit          59029 makeshift   20u     IPv6 0x7784b9d42c30a203        0t0     TCP [::1]:9001 (LISTEN)
Code\x20Helper  99786 makeshift   27u     IPv6 0x7784b9d42c30bec3        0t0     TCP *:9001 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: 1) *"I am having trouble getting VSCode to connect to Xdebug"* It's Xdebug connects to VSCode and not other way around. 2) Xdebug log looks OK -- connection was established. But it provides no details at all. I'm not using VSCode myself so cannot say when it can produce such short conversation .. but it might be because path mappings are missing or wrong (so editor cannot map remote path to local one).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I figured out the issue I was exposing the port in the docker-compose file and that was blocking vscode from connecting. I updated the example repo.